# How can I get Siri to list all relationships?

Tags: siri

As can be seen in this screenshot:

[image: List of relatives and friends as specified in the main user contact.]

Siri seems to be able to list all of the relationships which it understands.

Does anybody know the command for this? I've not been able to work it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ask Siri "Who am I?", and then scroll down.

[image: Poorly photoshopped Siri Screenshot]

Comment: Accepting a question is rep enough. Although when you do have rep, an upvote would still be awesome :).

Comment: As an aside, this photoshop is terrible, but that just proves the level of detail in the style Apple employs. Just wanted to point that out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to make Siri display a list, but you can see all of your relationships on your contact card. Just go to Contacts and select your name, and it will display all of your relationships too.